# How to hide / remove windows Taskbar (statusbar) in wpf application?

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I have a application that close login window when open dashboard windows.

```
LoginCommand = new RelayCommand<Window>(win =>
 {
  if (ValidateObject())
   {
    DashboardView view = new DashboardView();
    DashboardViewModel vm = new DashboardViewModel();
    view.DataContext = vm;
    view.Show();
    win.Close();
   }
 }
});
```

But in taskbar i have two windows.

How to hide/remove it?

Comment: view.ShowInTaskbar = false;

Comment: thanks, but this remove all windows in taskbar, but i want rwmove one of them.

Comment: Taskbar.visibility = visibility.hidden; and Taskbar.visibility = visibility.visible;

Comment: ShowInTaskbar will only remove the window on which you set the property on.

Comment: @mm8, I have two windows on taskbar , and when i set ShowInTaskbar =false , i have not any windows on taskbar.